# Array of unicode literals

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, unicode

I'm writing code that's supposed to be Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+ compatible. When trying to run my code with Python 2.7, I get the following problem.

I'm importing `unicode_literals` from `__future__` in each file and I'm having trouble getting the `array` function to work.

```
from array import array
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Trying to make a character array doesn't work

```
array("c", "test")
> TypeError: must be char, not unicode
```

Trying to make a unicode array also doesn't work

```
array("u", "test")
> TypeError: must be char, not unicode
```

Can I make an `array` that is compatible with `unicode_literals`?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `list`?

Comment: @Ownaginatious I'm working on legacy code so I would rather not have to rewrite the function to use `list`, that might be the best option, though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error is being thrown because of the first argument to `array()`, the typecode. In Python 2 this must be a non-unicode character (string of length 1), and in Python 3 this must be a unicode character. Since both of these are the meaning of `str` in the respective Python versions, this works in both:

```
array(str('u'), 'test')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of the array module that was fixed recently (https://bugs.python.org/issue20014).  On Python 2.7.11 (or newer) the array constructor will accept both `str` and `unicode` as the first argument.

As a workaround you can use e.g. `array(str("u"), "test")`.  I'm referring to the other answer by Dan Getz for an explanation of why this works.

Note that your first example using the "c" typecode still won't work on either Python 2.7 or Python 3.x.  On Python 2.7, you need to pass a bytestring as the second argument (e.g. by passing `b"test"` as the second argument).  The "c" typecode was removed in Python 3.0, so you should use "b" or "B" instead.